# How to throttle my browser-based application's API requests?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a browser-based app to look up and download data (in the form of .csv files) from https://api.discogs.com/.

After a successful trial with an input file containing a few items to look up, I tried to progress to larger input files of 30 or more lines, however I got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnQcM.jpg). It seems I am exceeding the rates specified [here](https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:home,header:home-rate-limiting).

So how can I throttle my application's requests locally as mentioned?

I suppose the code I will need to add to will be one or more of the following sections:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET',
`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${searchDetails}`);
request.send();
```

or

```
    function getReleases(id) {
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET',
      `https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`);
      request.send();
```

or

```
function getRelease(id) {
  return fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'CSV for Discogs/0.1',
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(parseReleaseData)
  }
```

TIA

Edit: someone on another forum suggested using the `Window setInterval()` method, but I'm not really sure how to code it. If I do, say...

```
setInterval(getRelease(), 1000);

function getRelease(id) {
  return fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'CSV for Discogs/0.1',
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(parseReleaseData)
  }
```

...won't that go into a loop, trying to run the code repeatedly every second?

Edit2: I tried that, but it just got stuck in a loop with the API server, before I had even had a chance to input any data to the app.

Comment: Have you bothered to read the api docs for the api you are using? They have a whole section on rate limiting and how you can detect when you are nearing the limit.  Read the [docs](https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:home,header:home-rate-limiting). Check the header for X-Discogs-RateLimit-Remaining, if you are getting close to 0 set a delay to wait a minute or so to free up your requests.

Comment: Yes, I have 'bothered to read' it, I did link it after all. Why would I link it if I hadn't read it? "Check the header for X-Discogs-RateLimit-Remaining" - and how do I do that exactly? "if you are getting close to 0 set a delay to wait a minute" - again, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to maintain a chain of promises to keep track of the requests:

```
  const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  let requests = Promise.resolve();

  function getRelease(id) {
   const apiCall = requests.then(() =>
    fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`, {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'CSV for Discogs/0.1',
      }
    })   
   );

   // add to chain / queue 
   requests = apiCall.then(response => 
    +response.headers.get("X-Discogs-Ratelimit-Remaining") <= 1 && timer(60 * 1000)
   );

   return apiCall
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(parseReleaseData);
  }
```

Now one request will be done after another, and if the rate limit gets reached it waits a minute.

You might want to retry in case of a rate limiting error. You could also add multiple promise queues to allow for higher throughput.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, this looks ideal, but for some reason when I try it I'm not getting any output at all, and there is nothing in the console to guide me either. Any ideas what to try next? cheers

Comment: Hmm ... could you add some logs to verify which parts of the promise chain do execute ... ?

Comment: That's interesting, after a long delay (a minute or so), I got an output from 5 lines of input. I'm going to try some tests with larger files now. In answer to your question I'm not sure what logs to add or where I would find them, sorry.